# Output of lti system in matlab doesn't look as expected

Tags: matlab, control-theory

I have designed a low-pass filter with cut-off frequency at 4.82 kHz. The script below contains the transfer function, creates a periodic triangular pulse and passes it through the filter.

```
h=tf([8.06 *10^22],[1 9.801*10^4 4.803*10^9 1.455*10^14 2.723*10^18 2.549*10^22])
T = 10*(1/2000);
Fs = 80000;
dt = 1/Fs;
t = 0:dt:T-dt;
x = sawtooth(2*pi*2000*t,0.5);
lsim(h,x',t')
```

My question is: shouldn't the output also be a triangular pulse,since this is a linear system? If no,can someone explain to me theoritically why this is an accepted output? If yes, is there some adjustment to the code I can make to get the correct output?

Comment: Your question might be better suited to [dsp.se], however I don't see why it should still be triangular just because the system is LTI. For example if your system is a high-order low pass filter that greatly dampens all harmonics beyond your lowest frequency you will be left with a sine-wave. The higher order harmonics are still present, but they are so small that they cannot meaningfully alter the shape of the sinusoid anymore (the way they were previously interfering to create the sawtooth shape). I have not looked at you code btw, just saying LTI systems can change wave shapes

Comment: I get what you are saying,but the signal passed has a frequency of 2 KHz, so the filter should leave it unaffected,right? The fact is that it smooths everything above 100 Hz

Comment: I think your question is more about filter design that Matlab implementation and you should consider moving it to [dsp.se] instead. I think you'll get more insightful answers there.

Answer (score 0):

No, an LTI real rational system necessarily smooths its input. You can convince yourself by thinking that in time domain an LTI system is a convolution operator. Alternatively, you can see that your system is a low-pass filter with roughly 6kHz bandwidth.

So you can multiply the frequency response of your system with the sawtooth spectrum to see what the answer would look like in the frequency domain.

Linearity is not a "shape" preserving property. It says if I get `r1` as the response to `i1` input signal and `r2` to `i2` then I will get `3*r1 + 5*r2` if I supply the input signal `3*i1 + 5*i2`.

What you might be looking for is reference tracking for a control system that requires a controller to drive the system such that the difference between the input and the output is minimized.

Comment: Thanks,  I see my misconception

Comment: @blindeyes My pleasure.